# Official references for default values of concurrent HTTP/1.1 connections per server?

Tags: http, browser, documentation

I am trying to complete a list of **offical documentation references** about the **default values*** of the maximum concurrent HTTP/1.1 connections per server for current (2011) major browsers.

Here's what I've got so far:

- Firefox 4.x: 6 (*ref missing*)
- [Firefox 3.6.x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest): **6**
- [Internet Explorer 9.x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/ee330731%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx#http11_max_con): **6**
- [Internet Explorer 8.x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): dialup: **2**, broadband: **6**
- [Internet Explorer 7.x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): dialup: **2**, broadband: **2**
- [Chrome 11.x](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack#TOC-Connection-Management): **6**
- [Chrome 10.x](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack#TOC-Connection-Management): **6**
- [Opera 11.x](http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/index.dml#performance): **8**
- Safari 5.x: 6 (*ref missing*)

I think most (if not all) of the default values I listed *should* be correct, but I'd prefer to have official documentation references which prove that.

Is anybody aware of such offical documentation references?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

<sub>* How to tweak this values by registry/console, or how to optimize by CDNs/CNAMEs is **not** the target of this question.</sub>

Comment: Ok, I'll bite.  What do you plan to do with this info?  Any browser worth using today has at least 6 concurrent connections per server.  I can't see what you plan to do with this info other than use the stats to try and convince IE6/IE7 users to upgrade?

Comment: @scunliffe: I just don't like to base parallelizing optimizations on assumptions (no, not even my own^^). That's all. My current infos are partially outdated and contain too much assumptions. That's why I asked for official references to get up-to-date again.  And no, my question was in **no way** meant to start any kind of browser war, nor to convince people to use another browser. If it sounded like that, I appologize (not a native speaker).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

Comment: You can find some stats on browsers in the wild at http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network