# Outgoing Network Connections for FireFox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, networking, google-chrome

What is the maximum number of outgoing network connections that the latest Chrome and FireFox can handle? This is for things like AJAX calls. I can't find any official documentation.

Can replies please provide official Mozilla/Google documentation stating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5751515/725163).  I think the standard is 6 per domain, and unfortunately this link only gives you a FF reference, not Chrome, but I hope it helps get you started in the right direction.