# Script is played in a different browser

Tags: loadrunner

I record my scrript in FireFox browser. While recording the script, the FF browser is opened and the user actions are recorded. However, when I play the script, the test results window shows that they are executed in a browser that is not supported. Most probably the application is opened in IE6/7.

I have changed the settings from Run-Time Settings->Browser->Browser Emulation but no success.

The user agent string is

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0

I am using Loadrunner v24.0

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly what you did in LoadRunner 12.01 (beta) and it worked perfectly. I also asked the developer responsible for this feature and he assured me that it worked this way in all previous versions. Also note that the replay is done using a smart browser emulator and not a real browser to reduce footprint.

Comment: You didn't mention which protocol you used so I assumed Web Http/Html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012262/load-testing-tools-and-concurrent-connections-per-server-browser-simulation/22015156#22015156