# What happens if browser agent is changed while replaying loadrunner web protocol script?

Tags: controller, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Lets say I ran a LR script consists of usual web http/html protocol with the browser agent of Internet Explorer 8(IE8) using LR 11. The script were created using same LR version but with IE11. Kindly provide information whether this change in browser version affects anything & how exactly.

Also, please tell what happens for similar case if the record is done using LR12- IE11 & replay using LR11 - IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server does not generate dynamic pages based upon browser type and version, then nothing from a server perspective.  You may need to alter your number of download threads to accurately model a given browser however.

This thread should add some insight on the connections front

[Load testing tools and concurrent connections per server browser simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012262/load-testing-tools-and-concurrent-connections-per-server-browser-simulation/22015156#22015156)

Comment: Thanks James, the thread does provide some key aspects.  However, from an another angle, does this change in browser affects anyway the compatibility? I mean if the site itself is designed to be compatible with upgraded IE, by creating/running LR script in lower version affects much?

Comment: @Swarup As long as the application responds to the particular script, there shouldn't be any cause for concern. Even if the site itself is designed to render appropriately only with a particular version of IE, as long as your response is as expected, load testing can continue without any issues. However, when you create scripts with a lower version of IE, you need to ensure that all the requests are appropriately captured. In the case of higher versions, there are no issues while recording or replaying.

Comment: Changing the user agent to a lower IE level could have issues on page level generation.   Some of the older IE browsers required HTML constructs which were slightly off compared to standard HTML, so you may have either no browser agent condition on page generation and it produces pure HTML, or it may respond simply with a generated page of "browser not supported...."