# In Loadrunner, is there a way to run HTML requests in parallel?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen, microfocus

When I check the calls' waterfalls in dev tools, there are 3 calls that run in parallel (roughly) to each other. I understand resources can be loaded in parallel with "concurrent", but I couldn't find a way to run these HTML calls in parallel. Is there a way I can run these requests in parallel? My response time for the transaction is much higher than the manual time due to this.

Running on Version 12.60

Comment: does by default. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012262/load-testing-tools-and-concurrent-connections-per-server-browser-simulation

Comment: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020/help/function_reference/Content/FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_concurrent_start.htm

Comment: Thank for the reply. I read through and looked at it. You seem to be correct based on what I see, but my timing still seems to be off. 
For example, I have three requests that are supposed to be parallel. In the snapshot the resp times are 200ms, 300ms, and 1000ms. The full txn time is marked as 1.6sec. I know that the vugen functions take some time, but I would expect it to be more like 1.2s, as the 3 calls should be running simultaneously.

Comment: I know they are shorter response times for that example, but thats just the one I had on hand.

Comment: See web_concurrent_[start|end] to force parallelism in requests