# Parallel call simulation in loadrunner

Tags: concurrency, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am building a Vugen script for the attached call.In the timeline snip 1,2,3 are parallel calls,they can be put inside web_concurrent_start and end. I want to know about call 4,5,6 they are not waiting for the response of 1,2,3 ...Should 4,5 and 6 also needs to be kept inside concurrent block? How to simulate all of request in the similar pattern[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7kse.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

This is handled automatically based upon your browser definition.   Six threads are the norm for modern browsers.

Keep them inside of the web_concurrent

Comment: Thank you. So all the calls are parallel except the one before marked number 1? If so why there is a time gap between 4 & 5 or 5&6 if the browser can handle 6 req concurrently from same host?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012262/load-testing-tools-and-concurrent-connections-per-server-browser-simulation/22015156#22015156